# Why are answers that recieved bounties from sockpuppets deleted, instead of just removing the bounties, and why can't they be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, bounty, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

*It is **not** an objection, I just post this question to know and discuss about a solution to some deleted posts.*

More than 15 months ago, I was cheating on Stack Overflow to earning more reputations, On 14th Jan 2019 one the moderator finds me as a sockpuppet maker and deleted all of them. He acted truly and there is no doubt on it. I was in the wrong way and I should understand the community purpose.

After one year of restriction for making sockpuppet accounts and voting irregularly, I decided to be loyal and follow the community rules. I don't wanna say I'm a repentant but I'm trying to act in have a better community.

Today I'm reviewing the years of activating on Stack Overflow and suddenly I found this:

[image]

I know the votes and the reps earned by an irregular, irrelevant and illegal actions should be deleted, that's right, **But why the possible true answers should be deleted**?

Some of my answers earn vote by cheating, that's right, the moderator can revert the votes. but the post still is existed and could help someone. **Why it should be deleted**?

Even it cannot get votes to undelete because *A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted*.

**My question is not an objection**, even I don't care about reputations. my exact mean is ***After the finding the cheater and punishing him/her, still his/her post can help somebody else***.

Here is some deleted post of mine, some JavaScript developers can review them, they could be correct for someone:

- [Unexpected status SERVICE_START_PENDING in response to START control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28171924/6877799)

  [image]
- [Node and npm too slow to start after install of macOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53602337/6877799)

  [image]
- [How to configure .babelrc to support ES6 module imports and async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53540716/6877799)

  [image]
- [How to handle weirdly combined websocket messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51704138/6877799)

  [image]
- [Vue - Compile other folder outside of /src in Vue.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52634079/6877799)

  [image]

Comment: If the answers are so awesome can't you just repost them and then refrain from voting on those with your socks?

Comment: Some users just leave downvote, without any reason. I asked a simple question for moderator deleted posts. Why it should get downvotes? I think it happens because the downvotes don't have side effects.

Comment: dear @rene, please pay attention, I banned for one year. so during this year cannot repost the answer, I don't mean my answers are awesome, no, it's just a conceptual issue. why the answer should be deleted? it maybe helps many users. just it.

Comment: The question reads a bit as a rant / mod attack / disgruntlement about stuff that happened over a year ago. The tone earns you down votes. And undeleting those answers would return the bounties which I guess were earned due to your sock puppeting. That is why the answers can't and shouldn't be undeleted ever. Not playing by the book should never be rewarded. I offered you a solution, maybe you can reword your question to ask if you are allowed to re-post those answers.

Comment: Dear @ModusTollens, downvotes has negative energy, the question has no similar in the meta, if somebody don't accept it, tell it on comment. downvotes make my heart cold.

Comment: Downvotes have no energy; they are numbers. If they make your heart cold, that's on you.

Comment: @AmerllicA I removed my comment because I believe the one posted by rene is spot-on. Downvotes should not make your heart cold - they are not meant to judge _you_. They indicate how users feel about your _post_. You can edit your post to influence the reception.

Comment: [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) notices on the answer screen shots seem to indicate that these were auto-awarded because answer had upvotes when bounty expired. If these upvotes were due to voting fraud then it would be fair to remove a bounty gained in a fraudulent way, and the only way technically allowing a moderator to do this is deletion of the answer. If you really want to honestly recover from past fraud and believe that deleted answers are worthy, consider simply reposting them, so that these won't be tainted with a past fraud

Comment: Dear @rene, yes you exactly right, so the community can undelete the answers, and delete the bounty, is it possible? the bounty earned maybe by sockpoppeting, but it can be deleted but still the post remains.

Comment: I already told you to reword and ask if you're allowed to repost the answers. Undeleting is not going to happen.

Comment: Dear @gnat, yes you right, the bounties were earned by cheating, but I mean, moderators should have tools to remove cheating bounties, but remain the posts.

Comment: We do not have such tools. Instead, we simply remove the fruit of the poisoned tree. If you think the answers were valuable, and you are the one who originally posted them, I recommend *reposting* them with your legitimate account, as @rene suggested.

Comment: Thanks dear @CodyGray, but if the moderators have a tool to remove the cheated bounty, it will be awesome. ok, thanks

Comment: Alternatively: it would be awesome if people didn't cheat, and we didn't have to spend time building tools around it.

Comment: Dear @CodyGray, I'm sorry, I apologize, I was in a wrong way. , I'm so sorry and ashamed of my deeds.

Comment: I am sure that SO would be able to develop tools to fix your problem.  Development costs being what they are, I suggest that you contract SO staff to do it at, say, $100/hr with  $1000 up front.  Would that be OK?

Comment: @MartinJames, I re-posted the answers that I believe they are valuable. I don't want to have more costs for the community. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moderators don't have tools for removing assigned bounties. for such this case the post with cheating bounty should be deleted. if the cheater answer owner thinks still the answer is valuable, he/she could re-post it.

Comment: side note regarding your other recent (deleted) question, primary goal of a moderator should be to discourage repeat abuse (evading suspension in the case you asked about). If they picked account merge, this would transfer rep and bounties to main account, making it look like a reward for a "clever trick". With this in mind, account deletion appears to be the only way to help abuser realise that repeating this won't benefit their main account

Comment: @gnat , see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63976087/6877799

Comment: @gnat , you can see there is no cheat on this post but Martijn use a SQL query to revert it, you cannot see it on my earned bounties. anyone doesn't answer me. it is my right.